# How to create a dynamic solver (optimization function) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, solver, pulp

Now, I have a question about the dynamic constraints. I have the original price, but I need to check if they follow the business rules, when there's a violation, I change the price, but I want the total absolute changes to be minimize.

My table columns look like this:

- item: String
- Size: Float
- Total_Amount: Int
- Original_Price: Float
- Optimal_Price:Float (Blank because this is decision variable)
- D1 (Blank but has formulas to get it)
- D2 (Same)
- Absolute (Blank, this is decision variable also objective column)

Here's my problem:

- Decision Variable:

1. optimal_price
2. Absolute_value (but this is still a linear function, please see the following)

- Objective: Minimize the sum of Absolute_value. SUM(Absolute)
- Constraints:

1. Absolute_value >= Difference_1
2. Absolute_value >= Difference_2
3. optimal_price >= 0
4. Same item, larger size optimal price >= smaller size optimal price
5. Same size, items also has price rules

For now, I am trying to achieve the first three constraints. I can easily do this in Excel, but so hard to move it to Python.

Here's the issue, I tried to calculate Difference_1 and Difference_2, but it requires me to bring decision variable, which is the optimal price into the function. Function is like:

- Difference_1 = (original_price - optimal_price)*total_amount
- Difference_2 = (optimal_price - original_price)*total_amount

Why we doing this is to get a linear solution instead of using absolute function.

I tried to use pulp to create this optimization function, but when I tried to add LpVariable into the Difference calculations,

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    D1[i] = (Opt_Price[i]-df['Original_Price'][i])*df['Total_Amount'][i]
    D2[i] = (df['Original_Price'][i]-Opt_Price[i])*df['Total_Units'][i]
```

it says

```
TypeError: 'LpVariable' object is not subscriptable
```

I also tried this:

```
D1 = (Opt_Price-df['Original_Price'])*df['Total_Amount']
D2 = (df['Original_Price']-Opt_Price)*df['Total_Amount']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made `Opt_Price` a single LpVariable, rather than a dictionary containing them. It's pretty standard to use `LpVariable.dicts` to make a dictionary of variables from a list of keys, like this:

```
Opt_Price = LpVariable.dics("optprices", range(df.shape[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tired this code, but then I got Opt_Price like this
 `{0: Opt_Price_0,
 1: Opt_Price_1,
 2: Opt_Price_2,
 3: Opt_Price_3,
 4: Opt_Price_4,
 5: Opt_Price_5,
 6: Opt_Price_6,
 7: Opt_Price_7
...}` It's a list of names, I don't know how to add this into the calculation function...